# Input Box Validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I Need a custom form validation in a textbox

The value should be like this `3-5`, so `<number>-<number>`

Please suggest me some ideas

Comment: what does mean by this <number>-<number> is this magneto specific

Comment: text box validation it's like magento custom validation class

Comment: Number should be 3-5 like wise it validate

Comment: i will suggest you. first you have to do some codding. please try and ask  if you found any complicated error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like (Jquery solution):

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var checkValue = $('#test').val();
    var check = (/^\d+-\d+$/).test(checkValue);
    if(check){
        alert('good data');
    }
    else{
        alert('bad data');
    }


});
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/fes7g1zf/1/